# no scope in loop $http get?

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, scope, http-get

I am using 2 API Points.
First one is to get all the exchanges and the second to print the BTC price on every exchange from the first point. I then want to combine both calls to 1 Object

```
var app = angular.module("App", []);   
app.controller("Ctrl", function ($scope, $http) {
    var rand = [];
    $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/all/exchanges" 
    }).then(function success(response) {
        var datas = response.data;
        for (var prop in datas) {

            $http.get("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=BTC&tsyms=USD&e=" + prop)
            .then(function success(responsePrice) {
            rand.push({'exchange' : prop, 'price' : responsePrice.data});
            })
        }

    });
    console.log(rand);
});
```

API points are working fine if i dont put them together. Is it bad to have a loop in my http get? Seems that i have no scope after the success function, so prop is always displayed as the last exchange.
Would be very thankful for help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scope for `prop` will always be lost because of `async` task in the loop. To retain the scope of `prop` you have to use `let` instead of `var` because `var` have `function` scope and and `let` have `block` scope. So your modified code will be as

```js
var app = angular.module("App", []);   
app.controller("Ctrl", function ($scope, $http) {
    var rand = [];
    $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/all/exchanges" 
    }).then(function success(response) {
        var datas = response.data;
        for (let prop in datas) {

            $http.get("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=BTC&tsyms=USD&e=" + prop)
            .then(function success(responsePrice) {
            rand.push({'exchange' : prop, 'price' : responsePrice.data});
            })
        }

    });
    console.log(rand);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, your following loop has problem:

```
      for (var prop in datas) {

            $http.get("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=BTC&tsyms=USD&e=" + prop)
            .then(function success(responsePrice) {
            rand.push({'exchange' : prop, 'price' : responsePrice.data});
            })
        }
```

The line `for (var prop in datas) {` executes all of its iteration and 
 points to the last element before finish the  `$http.get` request as its 
 asynchronous request.

So, to achieve this, some mechanism need to ensure the valid data 
 present at the time of `$http.get` call.

Now to do this, an array has been created by using the following code 
 as the return value is a map and its difficult to use in next recursive 
 function:

```
datas = response.data;
console.log(datas);
for (var prop in datas) {
   propArray.push(prop);
}
```

The following recursive function ensures the value of your used `prop` item updated after each `$http.get` has been completed:

```
var dataAcquireLoop = function () {
    dataIndex++;
    if(dataIndex >= propArray.length) {
        console.log(rand);
        return;
    }
    console.log(propArray[dataIndex]);
    $http.get("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=BTC&tsyms=USD&e=" + propArray[dataIndex])
    .then(
        function success(responsePrice) {
            rand.push({'exchange' : propArray[dataIndex], 'price' : responsePrice.data});
            dataAcquireLoop();
        },
        function(error) {
            dataAcquireLoop();
        }
    );

}
```

> The final updated code given below:

```
app.controller("Ctrl", function ($scope, $http) {
var rand = [];
var datas = [];
var dataIndex = -1;
var propArray = [];
var dataAcquireLoop = function () {
    dataIndex++;
    if(dataIndex >= propArray.length) {
        console.log(rand);
        return;
    }
    console.log(propArray[dataIndex]);
    $http.get("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=BTC&tsyms=USD&e=" + propArray[dataIndex])
    .then(
        function success(responsePrice) {
            rand.push({'exchange' : propArray[dataIndex], 'price' : responsePrice.data});
            dataAcquireLoop();
        },
        function(error) {
            dataAcquireLoop();
        }
    );

}

$http({
    method: "GET",
    url: "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/all/exchanges" 
}).then(function success(response) {
    datas = response.data;
    console.log(datas);
    for (var prop in datas) {
       propArray.push(prop);
    }
    dataAcquireLoop();
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var app = angular.module("App", []);
app.controller("Ctrl", function ($scope, $http) {
    var rand = [];
    $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/all/exchanges"
    }).then(function success(response) {
        var datas = response.data;
        var keys = Object.keys(datas);
        var promises = keys.map(prop =>
            $http.get("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=BTC&tsyms=USD&e=" + prop));

        Promise.all(promises).then((response) => {
            rand = response.map((responsePrice, index) => {
                return {
                    'exchange': keys[index],
                    'price': responsePrice.data
                };
            });
            console.log(rand);
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately the exchanges are  'undefined'